# Resetting jQuery 'On Click' Binders When New Links Added

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var links = $('body').find('a.internal');

    links.on('click', function(e){
        //pull page with ajax and replace the content with this response

        //replace current links, as some are added from ajax response
        links = $('body').find('a.internal');

        e.preventDefault();
    })
});
```

I'm guessing since there was only ever one `links.on()` called when the document was ready, it's never 'updated' with any new links that might be created. How would I go about resetting this binder after my ajax call?

**Thanks for the quick response. That did the trick!**

Comment: Event Delegation: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want this:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.internal', function(e){
    //pull page with ajax and replace the content with this response

    //replace current links, as some are added from ajax response
    links = $('body').find('a.internal');

    e.preventDefault();
})
```

This attaches the click event to the body and filters on a.internal. This will work if any new links are added to the page.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is attach the binding to the body and use the optional selector parameter.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('body').on('click', 'a.internal', function(e){
        //pull page with ajax and replace the content with this response

        //replace current links, as some are added from ajax response
        links = $('body').find('a.internal');

        e.preventDefault();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This http://api.jquery.com/live/ will handle all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future

Comment: jQuery live() has been removed from jQuery as of version 1.9 http://api.jquery.com/live/ .. best to use on()

Answer (score 0):

[rojoca's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19303699/1273830) answer is the right way to do it, but this is really what you asked for:

```
function ajaxDone() {
    $('a.internal').unbind('click').bind('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```